# Angular Http Get return different in Chrome/Safari vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I has one Http Get in angular 4, but body response is different in Chrome/Safari vs Firefox

My request is:

```
this.http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B250MRS8iWM0UFRfc3BBaWRfUlU').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the body response.
  console.log(data);
});
```

My response:

- In Chrome/Safari:
  [image: Safari (Webkit) response]
- In Firefox:
  [image: Firefox response]

  FIREFOX HEADER:
  [image: FIREFOX HEADER]

Anybody can help me? or Any ideas for this problems?

[UPDATED body response:]

+Safari:

1
00:00:24,213 --> 00:00:29,376
Dịch bởi: Nhung Nhung.

2
00:01:23,835 --> 00:01:24,738
Thế nào rồi?

3
00:01:25,130 --> 00:01:27,378
Bà mẹ đang gào khóc
còn ông chú thì đang cáu ầm lên.

4
00:01:28,080 --> 00:01:30,495
- Bà ấy không có chồng à?
- Ly dị, một nách 4 con.

5
00:01:31,297 --> 00:01:33,143
Tôi đoán chắc Cha xứ đang muốn giúp thôi.

6
00:01:33,452 --> 00:01:34,540
Giúp?

+Firefox:

```
��1
```

00:00:24,213 --> 00:00:29,376

D�ch b�i: Nhung Nhung.

2

00:01:23,835 --> 00:01:24,738

Th� n�o r�i?

3

00:01:25,130 --> 00:01:27,378

B� m� ang g�o kh�c

c�n �ng ch� th� ang c�u �m l�n.

4

00:01:28,080 --> 00:01:30,495

- B� �y kh�ng c� ch�ng �?
- Ly d�, m�t n�ch 4 con.

5

00:01:31,297 --> 00:01:33,143

T�i o�n ch�c Cha x� ang mu�n gi�p th�i.

6

00:01:33,452 --> 00:01:34,540

Gi�p?

7

00:01:37,685 --> 00:01:40,015

Ch�o �ng Burke, h� ang � �ng sau

n�i chuy�n v�i gi[…]

Comment: I guess that you do not need response in this form. Try console.log(data.json());

Comment: @JaroslawK. Thanks for your comment, But I need get text in body.

Comment: its a default HttpModule or custom?

Comment: @JaroslawK. Default HttpModule, I am using import like this: import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

Comment: @ThienSuBS if you want text you can do `data.text()`

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue in Firefox. What does the `content-type` header of the response look like?

Comment: @HarryNinh thank you, but the same problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, content-type is the same, you can see it in the picture (updated), I was try using encoding: 'Accept-Charset': utf-8

Comment: can you add the response from both instead of snapshots?

Comment: I think the problem is with the encoding of the Text. Try sending UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: Are you trying to send some kind of map or form data in response from server?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you're using the old `Http`, you need to do the following:

```
let url: string = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B250MRS8iWM0UFRfc3BBaWRfUlU';
this.http.get(url)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the body response.
        console.log(data);
     });
```

You are missing the map method, which maps the response back to json.

UPDATE to new HttpClientModule:

Add the following to your `app.module.ts`:

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

Inside your *.component.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

let url: string = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B250MRS8iWM0UFRfc3BBaWRfUlU';
    this.http.get<any>(url)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            // Read the result field from the body response.
            console.log(data);
         });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not working. I'm using the newest HTTP from https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: map is not mandatory, same can be done in subscribe. Also I would suggest use http from @angular/common/http instead of @angular/http as it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: Switching to HttpClient is not mandatory, it provides some extra features. Http should also do fine.

Comment: @SumitAgarwal, do you try my request and get any thing?

Comment: There is some problem with the url i guess, normal get request from browser on https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B250MRS8iWM0UFRfc3BBaWRfUlU , gave reply  as Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with